# Magento 2 : Execute Cron

Tags: magento2, cron, cli

How can I **execute Cron from command line manually.**

In Magento 1.x we can run cron like :

```
www.testsite.com/cron.php
```

but in magento 2 how can I do this ?

Please also help me for how can I execute cron from cmd. I already used below command which is not working :

```
sudo php bin/magento cron:run [--group="customgroupname_cron"]
```

This is returning exception :

```
[RuntimeException]   
Too many arguments.  

cron:run [--group="..."] [--bootstrap="..."]
```

------- Update -------

crontab.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">

    <group id="customgroupname_cron">
        <job name="customgroupname_cron" instance="Namespace\Modulename\Cron\Customcronjob" method="execute">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

In execute method of above file I put log. But after 1 minute also that is not generated.So how can I came to know that my method is executed.

Comment: It looks, to me a least, like you can still run them like Mage 1 by doing yoursite.com/update/cron.php

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't need the brackets when you run the command so you should run:

```
sudo php bin/magento cron:run --group="customgroupname_cron"
```

Comment: Yes this is giving a response that "Ran jobs by schedule". But please check my updated quetion.

Comment: @Krupali You also need to create a `cron_groups.xml` file in `etc` folder if you want to use your own special cron id.

Answer (score 10):

I merged the other answers from this post a bit - so that only one file is needed, and cron jobs can be run via browser or command line.

**Usage via command line:**

```
php cronLaunch.php "Vendor\Module\Class"
```

**Usage via browser:**

```
https://my.domain/hidden/cronLaunch.php?Vendor\Module\Class
```

**Installation**

I suggest to copy the source code from below and to store it in `src/pub/hidden/cronLaunch.php`. It is very important to protect the `hidden` directory from any unauthorized access!

```
<?php
require '../../app/bootstrap.php';
if (php_sapi_name() !== 'cli' && isset($_GET['job'])) {
    define('CRONJOBCLASS', $_GET['job']);
} elseif (php_sapi_name() !== 'cli') {
    die('Please add the class of the cron job you want to execute as a job parameter (?job=Vendor\Module\Class)');
} elseif (!isset($argv[1])) {
    die('Please add the class of the cron job you want to execute enclosed IN DOUBLE QUOTES as a parameter.' . PHP_EOL);
} else {
    define('CRONJOBCLASS', $argv[1]);
}

class CronRunner extends \Magento\Framework\App\Http
    implements \Magento\Framework\AppInterface
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $state,\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response)
    {
        $this->_response = $response;
        $state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
    }

    function launch()
    {
        $cron = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->create(CRONJOBCLASS);

        $cron->execute();
        return $this->_response;
    }
}

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('CronRunner');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

Thanks and credits to all the other people who posted answers here!

Answer (score 4):

```
cron:run [--group="..."] [--bootstrap="..."]
```

The `[]` brackets in a command line prototype merely indicate that the arguments they contain are optional.
In this case, it also states that they are chainable.

Answer (score 2):

To create a custom cron in Magento 2, follow these simple steps:

**Step 1: Create a Cron Group**

First, create a cron group in a file called cron_groups.xml located at `/Namespace/Modulename/etc/cron_groups.xml`.
Here's an example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/cron_groups.xsd">
    <group id="customgroupname_cron">
        <schedule_generate_every>1</schedule_generate_every>
        <schedule_ahead_for>4</schedule_ahead_for>
        <schedule_lifetime>2</schedule_lifetime>
        <history_cleanup_every>10</history_cleanup_every>
        <history_success_lifetime>60</history_success_lifetime>
        <history_failure_lifetime>600</history_failure_lifetime>
        <use_separate_process>1</use_separate_process>
    </group>
</config>
```

**Step 2: Assign Group ID to Your Cron**

In your `crontab.xml` file located at `/Namespace/Modulename/etc/crontab.xml`, assign the group ID you created to your custom cron job. Here's an example:

```xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="customgroupname_cron">
        <job name="custom_cron" instance="Namespace\Modulename\Cron\Customcronjob" method="execute">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

**Step 3: Flush Cache and Run Cron**

After making these configurations, flush the cache and run the cron command for your custom group using these commands:

```shell
php bin/magento c:f
php bin/magento cron:run --group="customgroupname_cron"
```

That's it! Your custom cron should now be up and running.