# Cron Job Set up in Windows

Tags: magento2, cron, magento-2.1, windows

How can I set up Magento 2 cron jobs to work on a Windows server?

I can make the cron tasks run in a [similar way to this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122081/magento-2-execute-cron) or by calling the file directly (as far as I can tell this works).

> yoursite.com/update/cron.php

However when trying to do extension installs Magento thinks that the cron process is not running ([Magento docs on this issue](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/cron.html)). How can I make it know it is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by running the correct command line task from the base magento install directory.

```
setup:cron:run
```

Make sure that your installs all use the same version of PHP and that the XSL extension is enabled otherwise this will cause issues as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run cron job directly without having to wait for the schedule, you can use

```
n98-magerun2 sys:cron:run <job name>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used "Task Scheduler" within Windows to achieve this. I create a task that ran every 5 minutes and for the action I set the following:

Program/script: `C:\xampp\php\php.exe`

Add arguments (optional): `C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\bin\magento cron:run`

The annoying thing about this is that you'll see php.exe pop up every time the cron runs. There's a work around for that, by changing the script to run as system. There's a [guide on how to do that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568736/how-do-i-set-a-windows-scheduled-task-to-run-in-the-background).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run the following command line:

```
php magento-installation-directory/bin/magento cron:run
```

You can also create cron job to run at a certain time interval if u dont want to run this command manually everytime

Comment: Is there anyway to run this same command from the browser do you know?

Comment: yes.First go to ur magento admin panel.Then go to stores->configuration->advanced->system.Now under cron(Scheduled tasks) u can configure cron job